# How to refresh text in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, text

I have this `Text`

[image]

I want when I clicked on add Icon to refresh 30 to 31

this is my code :

```
Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30.0,
                            width: 30.0,
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/trash_can.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              mealsNum.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              mealsNum++;
                              print(mealsNum);
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: Color(0xffFFD243),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can share your code please.

Comment: @Isaudon ok I will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a set state to update

```
 onTap: (){
    setState((){                                    
mealsNum++;
});

  print(mealsNum);,
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add setState in onTap

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 30.0,
        width: 30.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/trash_can.png'),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          mealsNum.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          setState(() {
            mealsNum++;
          });
          print(mealsNum);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Color(0xffFFD243),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

[setSate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) is used for rebuilding the widgets. Add setstate in onTap

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 30.0,
        width: 30.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/trash_can.png'),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          mealsNum.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          setState(() {
            mealsNum++;
          });
          print(mealsNum);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Color(0xffFFD243),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

you should learn `state management` in flutter here is the link to learn the basic from flutter [basic doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) after you read this you maybe ask what about `global state` or more complicated state mangement then you can choose [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or for more advance use [flutter_block](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) here is the link for [flutter_block library made with example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted)
,have a good luck with `state management`